# How to overrule Craft error messages with custom setError()?

Tags: plugin-development, error-message, events

I know I can set errors and notices in the CP with `setError()` and `setNotice()`.
But it gets overruled by the default error message in my event.

I have a `beforeDeleteEntry` event which stops the deleting of an entry by using `$event->performAction = false;`. This makes Craft display a default error "can't delete entry". I'd like to add more to that error or show another one, but using `setError()` does not work. A `setNotice()` is shown however so I suppose the error gets replaced by the default Craft error.

Can I do something about that?

Answer (score 1):

I recently asked P&T about a similar issue, although it was for the `onBeforeSaveEntry` event (not `onBeforeDeleteEntry`) -- it turns out that you need to set the error on a specific field, not the entry as a whole. I don't know if this is the case for your problem, but perhaps worth trying something like this:

`$event->params['entry']->addError('title', 'Cannot delete because blah blah blah');`